# QT restoreGeometry срабатывает слишком поздно

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Доброй ночи!
У меня тут какая-то непонятная ситуация. Например, в методе readMapSettings() в waterBody.setWaterBody(mapName); у меня происходит создание объектов и там очень важно, чтобы до их создания геометрия окна была уже полностью развернута - т.к. там внутри берутся размеры QLabel с QPixmap внутри. И эти размеры должны соответствовать полному окну(т.к. я закрыл приложение с полным окном), а значит открыться оно должно тоже с полным я ведь читаю из QSettings. Но в итоге в параметры объектов почему-то записываются width 100 и height 30, вместо 1004 и 977 соответственно. И уже потом это все дело через всякие эвенты приходит в норму, но с диким оверхедом. Я уже даже showEvent заюзал, чтобы гарантированно получить создание объектов уже после полностью развернутого главного окна. Но этого не происходит, я все равно получаю 100 и 30. Я сперва определяю qpixmap, затем читаю геометрию, потом уже создаю объекты, что еще ему надо??? Может есть возможность как-то дать команду развернуть окно сразу во чтобы то ни стало?
На всякий случай указываю, что у меня есть еще один важный перегруженный метод - resizeEvent(). Он используется для сохранения пропорций после scaleContents QLabel. Но влиять на проблему вроде не должен.

```
void MainWindow::readMapSettings() {

    QSettings settings(".//settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

    settings.beginGroup("MAPS");
    const QString mapName = settings.value("map", "MosquitoLake").toString();
    settings.endGroup();

    if(mapName == "CottagePond") {
        ui->labelImageMap->setPixmap(QPixmap(".//maps/Hootorez_CottagePond.jpg"));
        waterBody.setLabelImageMapPtr(ui->labelImageMap);
        readDisplaySettings();
        waterBody.setWaterBody(mapName);
        writeMapSettings(mapName);
    }
}

void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *event) {

    QMainWindow::showEvent(event);

    readMapSettings();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {

    if(!waterBody.getLabelImageMapPtr())
        return;

    int widthCurrentPixMap = 1;
    int heightCurrentPixMap = 1;

    const QPixmap* pixPtr = this->ui->labelImageMap->pixmap();
    if(pixPtr) {
        widthCurrentPixMap = pixPtr->width();
        heightCurrentPixMap = pixPtr->height();
    }
    const QSize pixmapSize(widthCurrentPixMap, heightCurrentPixMap);

    ui->labelImageMap->setFixedWidth(
        ui->centralWidget->height() * pixmapSize.width() / pixmapSize.height()
    );

    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: а вы можете написать основную идею, т.к. кажеться что подход вы выбрали явно не тот.

Comment: Ну, основная идея - на старте программы получить правильные координаты при создании объектов. Координаты зависят от текущего размера окна. Т.к. qsettings сохраняет геометрию в файл, а файл я при старте читаю, значит я должен получить координаты под ту геометрию, что считывается из файла. Геометрия срабатывает, но окно почему-то разворачивается позже, чем я создаю объекты, а значит не получаю правильные координаты под текущее окно, не смотря на, казалось бы, верную очередность операций.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем вы привязываете координаты к размеру окна (если мы говорим про координаты на карте). Но если вы хотите регулировать изначальные размеры, вам нужно посмотреть в сторону переопределения `sizeHint()`. Этот параметр отвечает за предварительные (рекомендованные) размеры.

Comment: В моем случае их больше не к чему привязать, кроме как к координатам QLabel.(я храню в файле процентное соотношение). Предварительные размеры мне не подходят. В каком размере пользователь закрыл программу, в таком она и должна восстановится, для такого размера и должны высчитаться координаты сразу после старта программы.

Comment: Берите в пример гугул карты. Масштаб карты там не меняется в зависимости от размера окна браузера. Вам тогда нужно привязываться к размеру самой картинки (оригинального размера) а дальше ее масштабировать. Интересно как у вас работает масштабирование и передвижение карты если вы используете только лейбл.

Comment: У меня меняется масштаб карты в зависимости от размеров окна. Я же написал, что у меня включен scaleContents  для qlabel. Такая реализация и я не хочу ее изменять. Она подходит мне на все 100%. Речь про то - почему восстановление геометрии окна после ее чтения из qsettings и отработки метода restoreGeometry так запаздывает?

Comment: Пробуйте через `sizeHint()`. По идее он вернет тот первый размер 100х30.

Comment: Имеется ввиду - перед закрытием программы, вписывать в файл настроек еще и данные для sizeHint(), а при старте программы, читать эти данные после geometryRestore(), но до создания объектов? Как-то костыльно, но если будет работать хоть так, то будет неплохо. Благодарю, попробую!

Comment: Нет, вы должны переопределить метод. Т.е. он должен возвращать данные которые вы считали с сетингов или дефолтный размер если их нет. `return QSettings().value("map", QWindow::sizeHint()).toSize()`. Возможно так вам получиться обойти двойной ресайзинг.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Сделал вот так для теста: `QSize sizeHint() const override; QSize MainWindow::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(1004, 977);
}` Но я даже не попадаю в этот метод.

Comment: Что то вы не правильно сделали, т.к. я только что собрал тест. В сайз хинт попадает, а на ресайзе `QSize(-1, -1)` меняется на `QSize(500, 500)'. 'QSize MainWindow::sizeHint() const { return QSize(500, 500); }; void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) { qDebug() << event->oldSize(); qDebug() << event->size(); };`